# How to sort heading and content elements as a group

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I want to make my divs sortable with jQuery UI but I have a few problems with it. `.content_left` is a div where the box should be able to change their position.

**HTML**

```
<script>$("#panel_test").sortable();</script>
<div class="content_left ui-sortable">
    <div id="panel_test">
         <div class="panelheadbar pgrau">Test</div>
         <div id="pc_test" class="panelcontent ui-resizable">text...</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But now I have the problem that I can change the position of `.panelheadbar` and `.panelcontent` individually.

**Image of the problem**

[image]

**Edit 1:** How can I connect two divs (content_left, content_right) in which I can drag div-boxes. And is it possible that the dragged box doesn't disappear under `.content_mid`?
[image]

Comment: Any reason you don't wrap the pairs in a container element, perhaps with the class `panel`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to remove the header from being able to sort:

```js
$('#panel_test').sortable({
  items: '> div:not(.panelheadbar)'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="panel_test">
  <div class="panelheadbar pgrau">Test</div>
  <div class="panelcontent ui-resizable">text 1</div>
  <div class="panelcontent ui-resizable">text 2</div>
  <div class="panelcontent ui-resizable">text 3</div>
  <div class="panelcontent ui-resizable">text 4</div>
  <div class="panelcontent ui-resizable">text 5</div>
  <div class="panelcontent ui-resizable">text 6</div>
</div>
```

If you want to move the header WITH the content:

```js
$('#panel_test').sortable({
  handle: '.panelheadbar' // Optional to make only the header move it.
});
```

```css
.panel_group {
  border:1px solid;
  padding:3px;
}
.panelheadbar {
  font-weight:bold;
  font-size:110%;
  background:lightgrey;
  cursor:move;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="panel_test">
  <div class="panel_group">
      <div class="panelheadbar pgrau">Header 1</div>
      <div class="panelcontent ui-resizable">Content 1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel_group">
      <div class="panelheadbar pgrau">Header 2</div>
      <div class="panelcontent ui-resizable">Content 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel_group">
      <div class="panelheadbar pgrau">Header 3</div>
      <div class="panelcontent ui-resizable">Content 3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel_group">
      <div class="panelheadbar pgrau">Header 4</div>
      <div class="panelcontent ui-resizable">Content 4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I doubt this would keep the headings and content divs grouped properly.

Comment: @isherwood The question is ambiguous. The image suggest option 1 would be the answer, however the code and description suggestions option 2. I was still writing when you commented :)

Comment: I have also a `content_right`-div. How can I add this so that I can drag boxes from the left site to the right site?

Comment: Add the [`connectWith`](https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-connectWith) field.

Comment: I added an image to my first post. `$(".content_left").sortable({
   handle: ".panelheadbar",
   connectWith: ".content_right"
  });` didn't work for me and if I drag a div-box to content_mid, it disappears under content_mid.

Comment: I would create a separate question for your other query regarding linking sortables.